# vsftpd with chroot_local_user requires client certificate

Tags: chroot, vsftpd, ftps

When setting up my FTPS server I want to enable chroot_local_user. When disabled everything works fine. If I enable this however, WinSCP fails to connect and claims I need a client certificate to connect. Filezilla fails outright.

If I explicitly set require_cert to NO (even if it is default), this issue still persists.

How can I solve this?

An alternative solution that limits users to their home folder would also be acceptable.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WinSCP error message is probably wrong (or mere speculation). When I tried to set up vsftpd with `chroot_local_user` a while ago I found out that vsftpd will reject logins (for security reasons) if the user has write permissions in the chroot directory. This is a little hidden in the [vsftpd FAQ](https://security.appspot.com/vsftpd/FAQ.txt):

> Q) Help! I'm getting the error message "refusing to run with writable root".
>
> A) vsftpd is protecting against dangerous configurations. The cause of this
>   message is usually dodgy ownership of the ftp home directory. The home
>   directory should NOT be owned by the ftp user itself. Neither should it
>   be writable by the ftp user. A way to fix this is:
>
> chown root ~ftp; chmod -w ~ftp
>
> Another cause might be an attempt to use chroot_local_user without setting up
>   the directory ownership properly.

To debug this, add `log_die=YES` to your vsftpd.conf. The log will then show something like this:

```
Nov 29 16:08:55 yourhost vsftpd[2866]: pam_userdb(vsftpd:auth): user 'testuser' granted access
Nov 29 16:08:55 yourhost vsftpd[2872]: ERROR: vsftpd: refusing to run with writable root inside chroot()
```

This is not a problem for read-only access, but if your users should be able to upload files, you have to create a folder in the chroot dir which is owned by the respective user. If you want to provide ftps access to your users' home directories, it gets a little cumbersome. You probably have to insert an additional hierarchy level, i.e. `/home/someuser` becomes `/home/someuser/someuser`.

For quick testing, I found that curl is quite handy, e.g. to test an upload:

```
curl -T /tmp/blub -u testuser:testpass ftps://yourserver.example.com/in/
```

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this issue. Cyberduck (and only Cyberduck) was requesting a client certificate to my vsftp server.

My solution was to add this to /etc/vsftpd.conf:

`ssl_request_cert=NO`